# module tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.compat has no attribute v1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3 and tensorflow 1.8.0 on Ubuntu

In `ipython notebook`, I ran:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input
tf.compat.v1.image.resize_bilinear()
```

But I get `attributeerror: module tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.compat has no attribute v1`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Updating Tensorflow solves this problem.

e.g. run `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow`

Comment: trying that, I get `modulenotfounderror: no module named tensorflow.compat`

Comment: @user5739619 Which tensorflow version are you using? Mine is 1.13.2. It might be helpful to upgrade: `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow`.

Comment: I was using 1.8. I upgraded to 1.14 so now I don't get that error. However, when I try `resize_bilinear()`, it says `missing 2 required positional arguments: images and size`. I was just trying the code from here: https://github.com/bonlime/keras-deeplab-v3-plus/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/test-checkpoint.ipynb`

Comment: That function requires two arguments which are image and the size. I don't think the third block in their code has any effects though. It's not executed since `In [ ]` doesn't have numbers in it. I think it's safe to just skip that block.